# Перенос Django проекта на виртуальный сервер Linux

Tags: python, linux, django, vps

Не получается это сделать, прошу помощи...
Что я делал:

1. Я установил разные python, postgresql и другие модули, которые были в разных инструкциях, по которым я пытался это сделать.
2. Я создал юзера postgresql, саму бд и познакомил их друг с другом
3. С помощью virtualevn создал окружение, активировал его, в нём установил `pip install django gunicorn psycopg2
4. Создал проект `django-admin.py startproject myproject .`
5. Копирнул с компа мой проект Django на Pycharm в этот созданный проект в 4-ом пункте с заменой файлов, когда спрашивало
6. Начать делать миграцию, но `./manage.py makemigrations` и `./manage.py migrate` не работало, появлялось это: `/usr/bin/env: 'python\r': No such file or directory`, но мне удалось сделать это с помощью `python ./manage.py makemigrations` и `python ./manage.py migrate`
7. Сервер запускается и вродё всё ок, но там у меня есть работа с БД и поэтому при заходе на сайт появляется такая писанина:

> IntegrityError at / insert or update on table "webexample_data"
>   violates foreign key constraint
>   "webexample_data_user_id_9a591628_fk_auth_user_id" DETAIL:  Key
>   (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user". Request Method:    GET
>   Request URL:  http://46.36.219.171:8000/ Django Version:  2.1 Exception
>   Type: IntegrityError Exception Value:  insert or update on table
>   "webexample_data" violates foreign key constraint
>   "webexample_data_user_id_9a591628_fk_auth_user_id" DETAIL:  Key
>   (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user". Exception
>   Location: /root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py
>   in _commit, line 239 Python
>   Executable:   /root/webserver/venv/bin/python Python Version: 3.5.3
>   Python Path:   ['/root/webserver',  '/usr/lib/python35.zip', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5',  '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
>   '/root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages'] Server time:  Чт, 9
>   Авг 2018 18:31:43 +0000

И ещё много всякого интересного... Тут я понял, что не хватает суперюзера и начал его создавать...

8. Команда python `./manage.py createsuperuser` посылает меня сюда фразой:

> utility.execute()   File
>   "/root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 316, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
>       return super().execute(*args, **options)   File "/root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 353, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 112, in handle
>       username = self.get_input_data(self.username_field, input_msg, default_username)   File
>   "/root/webserver/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 193, in get_input_data
>       raw_value = input(message) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Кто-нибудь подскажите, какую магию нужно использовать, чтобы создать суперюзера?
Или может быть я вообще всё не так делаю?
Мне очень нужна помощь, я в отчаянии и мне нужна помощь великих умов stackoverflow.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить скрипт таким образом: `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: @floydya, ошибка в целом примерно такая же вылезла, не знаю как её показать, т.к. комментарий разрывает от такого количества текста

Comment: @floydya, блин, афигеть, я вручную переписывал и упустил IO между PYTHON и ENCODING. Хорошо, что заметил это, когда коммент решил перечитать... Всё заработало, блин, расцеловал бы!
Срочно в ответ пишите и я залайкаю что есть мочи

Comment: Очень рад, что помогло :) Вам стоит добавить эту переменную в среду, чтобы не вызывать ее постоянно вручную(в UNIX сис-мах не особо шарю, но вроде нужно прописать в консоли `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: Лучший ответ на stackoverflow.com!
Берите пример с floydya и будьте такими же умничками!